# TableViewer Adding data from ArrayLists Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, jface

I have the following code that creates a `TableViewer`.

```
TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
Table table = viewer.getTable();
table.setHeaderVisible(true);
table.setLinesVisible(true);
```

How to create a `ContentProvider` in order to add data from array lists in the columns of the table?
I have these lists and I want to add them in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need one object per row in the table.

If you create an array or ArrayList containing a single object per row you can use the standard `ArrayContentProvider`:

```
viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
```

The row data class might be something like:

```
class RowData
{
  private String [] cols;

  RowData(String [] theCols)
  {
    cols = theCols;
  }

  String getColumn(int index)
  { 
    return cols[index];
  }
}
```

Create a array of these from your existing lists:

```
RowData [] rows = new RowData [listSize];

for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
 {
   rows[i] = new RowData(new String [] {col0List.get(i), col1list.get(i), ...});
 }
```

Set this as the input to the viewer:

```
 viewer.setInput(rows);
```

**But** only do this after setting the content provider and label provider in the viewer.

Use a label provider implementing `ITableLabelProvider`:

```
 class MyLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements ITableLabelProvider
 {
   @Override
   public String getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex)
   {
     RowData rowData = (RowData)element;

     return rowData.getColumn(columnIndex);
   }

   @Override
   public Image getColumnImage(Object element, int columnIndex)
   {
     return null;
   }
 }
```

Comment: I used this but I'm not able to put the lists as inputs to fill the columns of the table.

Comment: You need to create a new class containing all the data for a row and use that with the content provider and the label provider.